# Expo managed project release build apk failed to launch on emulator or device

Tags: react-native, expo

I created a new project and immediately converted it to managed project using `expo:eject`. Unfortunately, when I run `npx react-native run-android --variant release` it is throwing this error. The emulator opened and the apk was installed but did not start properly.

```
11:14:44 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on '59dfc475' : EOF hit. Read: -1
11:14:44 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installing APK 'app-release.apk' on 'MI PAD 4 - 8.1.0' for app:release
11:14:44 D/app-release.apk: Uploading app-release.apk onto device '59dfc475'
11:14:44 D/Device: Uploading file onto device '59dfc475'
11:14:44 D/ddms: Reading file permision of /Users/mjabadilla/dev/github/mjmaix/app-skeleton/AppSkeleton/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk as: rw-r--r--
11:14:45 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-release.apk"
11:14:49 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-release.apk"' on '59dfc475' : EOF hit. Read: -1
11:14:49 V/ddms: execute: returning
11:14:49 V/ddms: execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-release.apk"
11:14:49 V/ddms: execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-release.apk"' on '59dfc475' : EOF hit. Read: -1
11:14:49 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installed on 1 device.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, ejected projects (v37) that have the `expo-updates` module in it so `expo publish` must be executed before a release build.

You can read their official fyi for [Release builds with expo-updates](https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/master/release-builds-with-expo-updates.md#release-builds-with-expo-updates) if you want to know more